# Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'GlobalEventHandlers'. in Typescript

Tags: typescript

```
TypeScript error in D:/office-work/ma-web/src/@utils/uiUtils.ts(6,8):
```

Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'GlobalEventHandlers'.  TS2339

```
4 |         ) as HTMLDivElement
5 |         toggleElem.onclick = function () {
```

> 6 |                 this.classList.toggle("active")
> |                      ^
> 7 |         }
> 8 | }

**Code**

```
export const uiEventHandler = () => {
const toggleElem = document.querySelector(
    ".custom-dropdown-trigger"
) as HTMLDivElement
toggleElem.onclick = function () {
    this.classList.toggle("active")
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show the code that you are trying to execute?

Comment: export const uiEventHandler = () => {
 const toggleElem = document.querySelector(
  ".custom-dropdown-trigger"
 ) as HTMLDivElement
 toggleElem.onclick = function () {
  this.classList.toggle("active")
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are getting the element.

If so, you need to add the following:

```
toggleElem.addEventListener('click', callbackfn)

callbackfn() {
    this.classList.toggle("active")
}
```